# oauth2 spring-security should you be logged in before requesting a token or code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

I'm trying to setup oauth2 using spring-security (2.0.3.RELEASE) in a spring-mvc application, with a grant type of password.

When executing the following request to access a token:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?client_id=testclient&grant_type=password&username=user&password=test123&response_type=token"
```

I'm getting a:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.
```

When tracking down this exception I noticed it is originated at AuthorizationEndpoint.java line 137 wheren the code checks if the user is authenticated:

```
if (!(principal instanceof Authentication) || !((Authentication) principal).isAuthenticated()) {
```

I find this odd, should I first login and the post to the /oauth/authorize resource before trying to access the token ? 
If so why ? I'm already adding my password and username to the /oauth/authorize request. I don't see the benefit of being logged in before trying to get a hold of a token if you must supply the password and username again ?

Comment: I am getting same error while using version 2.0.6. for 'grant_type=authorization_code' and 'response_type=code'. Can you help me with this case?

Comment: Sure, what url are you using ? I was using the wrong endpoint/url ...

Comment: I have the same problem as Kumar, trying to get an auth code from oauth/authorize but the request fails with the InsufficientAuthenticationException though i cannot find anything wrong with my configuration .. has anyone been able to solve this?

Comment: For the authorization code I had the same problem when I used @EnableResourceServer in my authorization server. Please disable if you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong endpoint. If you're using the `password` grant, you should be sending the request to the token endpoint. See the [OAuth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) for details.

Comment: I'm not using the password grant type, but the `authorization_code` grant type. The Spring Security framework still tries to authenticate the user when the request hits the `/auth/authorize` endpoint. I get the same error message as in the question. How come the OAuth framework is not hit before ?

Comment: The user is supposed to be authenticated by the during the authorization code flow. This question is for Spring Security 2 and over 4 years old. I'd recommend you post your own question explaining what you're doing and how you intend to authenticate the user (resource owner).